# Confused about C++ nested dependent type name

Tags: c++, templates, using, typename

Effective C++ told me that I'd better use `typename` when encountered nested dependent type name.

The following example code is easy to understand:

```
template <typename ElementType>
class BST {
private:
  class LinkNode {
  public:
    ElementType data;
    LinkNode *left, *right;
    explicit LinkNode() {}
  };

public:
  void some_func();
}

template <typename ElementType>
void BST<ElementType>::some_func() {
  // or `using NodePtr = typename BST<ElementType>::LinkNode *;`
  typedef typename BST<ElementType>::LinkNode * NodePtr;
  ...
}
```

However, after I added using aliases in the template class BST, it seemed that keyword `typename` is not neccessary anymore.

Here you can see:

```
template <typename ElementType>
class BST {
private:
  class LinkNode {
  public:
    ElementType data;
    LinkNode *left, *right;
    explicit LinkNode() {}
  };

  using NodePtr = LinkNode *; // the only difference between these two code blocks

public:
  void some_func();
}

template <typename ElementType>
void BST<ElementType>::some_func() {
  // typename is not neccessary here!
  BST<ElementType>::NodePtr ptr;
  ...
}
```

Does anyone could figure out that?

Comment: The `typename` should be necessary the first time either. In `BST<ElementType>::some_func` just `typedef LinkNode *NodePtr` should work (though I can't stress strongly enough what a dreadful practice hiding pointer types under type aliases is).

Comment: `using` declares a type so there is no ambiguity requiring `typename` to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That effect is not directly tied to type alias through `using`, it's a result of name lookup for member of the current instantiation.

Inside `BST` both `BST` and `BST<ElementType>` expression refer to the current instantiation and the members of it can be found without the need of the prefix `typename` you could do:

```
template <typename ElementType>
void BST<ElementType>::some_func() {
    BST::NodePtr ptr; // or 
    BST<ElementType>::LinkNode * ptr2;
}
```

resulting in the same thing. But now let assume that `some_func` is also a template member function defined as:

```
template <typename ElementType>
struct BST {
    class LinkNode { /*...*/ };

    using NodePtr = LinkNode *;

    template <typename T>
    void some_func();
};


template <typename ElementType>
template <typename T>
void BST<ElementType>::some_func() {
    BST<T>::NodePtr ptr;     // (1)
    BST<T>::LinkNode * ptr2  // (2)
}
```

Now neither (1) nor (2) will compile because `B<T>` is no longer the current instantiation, hence in these cases you need `typename`.

The relevant part of the standard `[temp.res]/7`:

> Within the definition of a class template or within the definition of a member of a class template following the declarator-id, the keyword typename is not required when referring to the name of a previously declared member of the class template that declares a type or a class template. [...]